# Getting id from row clicked on a dgrid List

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I just started using dgrid, and going through the dTunes sample, I'm unable to find the id associated with each row in the list.  This is pretty remedial on my part, but how would I also get the id I sent from the datasource?

```
 define([
'require',
'dgrid/List',
'dgrid/OnDemandGrid',
'dgrid/Selection',
'dgrid/Keyboard',
'dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider',
'dojo/_base/declare',
'dojo/_base/array',
'dojo/Stateful',
'dojo/when',
'dstore/RequestMemory',
'put-selector/put',
'dojo/domReady!'
 ], function (require, List, Grid, Selection, 
        Keyboard, Hider, declare, arrayUtil, Stateful, 
        when, RequestMemory, put) {

 var cstsNode = put(listNode, 'div#cstsCars');
 ...

var cstsList = new TunesList({}, cstsNode);
var dataCSTS = new RequestMemory({ target: require.toUrl('./dataCSTS.json') });

...

dataCSTS.fetch().then(function (cars) {
    cstsCars = arrayUtil.map(cars, pickField('Description'));
    cstsCars.unshift('All (' + cstsCars.length + ' CSTS Cars' + (cstsCars.length !== 1 ? 's' : '') + ')');
    cstsList.renderArray(cstsCars);
});

...

cstsList.on('dgrid-select', function (event) {
    var row = event.rows[0];
    console.log(row.id);  // shows row number.  How do I get the real id or other fields?
    console.log(row.data);  // shows row text that is displayed ("sample text 1")
    console.log(row.data.id); // undefined
});
```

Here is a snippet of sample data like I'm supplying:

```
 [{"id":"221","Description":"sample text 1"},
 {"id":"222","Description":"sample text 2"}, 
 {"id":"223","Description":"sample text 3"}]
```

I'd like to see the id.  Instead, row.id returns 1,2 and 3, ie the row numbers (or id dgrid created?).

Comment: what do you mean by real id? can you provide more details with data? The `row.data` returns the actual data that is stored in object array which may or may not match the data that is displayed on the grid. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The `id` field will be in the `data` object. i.e `console.log (row.data.id)` and not `row.id`. The `row.id` is the internal representation of the dGrid.

Comment: Maybe there is something else wrong, because row.data.id is undefined, since row.data is just text.  Is my row object being defined right?

Comment: can you show us what are the contents of `row.data`? If it is a JSON string then you need to convert it into a JSON Array Object and use that as data for the grid.

Comment: You need to store the data as an Array Object. I think that is where the problem lies. It should be `var data = [{"id":"221","Description":"sample text 1"},
 {"id":"222","Description":"sample text 2"}, 
 {"id":"223","Description":"sample text 3"}];`

Comment: I'm still not sure what's going on, so I added more code that shows how that data is read in and converted.  The file contains the json string which I thought was being converted to the appropriate object.

Comment: The following line of code in your post `cstsReasons = arrayUtil.map(reasons, pickField('Description'));` only creates an array of objects with `Description` field. i.e ` [{"Description":"sample text 1"}, {"Description":"sample text 2"}, {"Description":"sample text 3"}]` Which is then given to dGrid for rendering. You need to construct the memory store will the whole data not just part of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73097/discussion-between-dave-and-frank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't really shown a complete example, but given that you're using a store anyway, you'd have a much easier time if you let dgrid manage querying the store for you.  If you use `dgrid/OnDemandList` (or `dgrid/List` plus `dgrid/extensions/Pagination`), you can pass your `dataCSTS` store to the `collection` property, it will render it all for you, and it will properly pick up your IDs (since `Memory`, and `RequestMemory` by extension, default to using `id` as their identity property).

The most appropriate place to do what you're currently doing prior to `renderArray` would probably be in the `renderRow` method if you're just using List, not Grid.  (The default in List just returns a div with a text node containing whatever is passed to it; you'll be passing an object, so you'd want to dig out whatever property you actually want to display, first.)

If you want a header row, consider setting `showHeader: true` and implementing `renderHeader`.  (This is false in List by default, but Grid sets it to true and implements it.)

You might want to check out the [Grids and Stores tutorial](http://dgrid.io/tutorials/0.4/grids_and_stores/).

Comment: I'm new to dGrid (and dojo) so thanks for your patience and clarifying things. I'll look into using OnDemandList.   I truly just need one column, so a list seems appropriate.

Comment: Actually I found little info on OnDemandList so I just changed those Lists to normal Grids and now everything is easy.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that I was modeling my code based on the dTunes sample code, which has 3 lists that behave a little differently than a regular grid.

For now, I'm using the cachingStore that is available in the lists.  So the way I get the id:

```
cstsList.on('dgrid-select', function (event) {
    var row = event.rows[0];
    var id = storeCSTS.cachingStore.data[row.id - 1].id; // -1 because a header was added
    console.log(id);
});
```

I'm not sure whether this will work if I ever try to do sorting.